# Change Jquery asPieProgress barcolor at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery asPieProgress plugin:
 https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-asPieProgress#options.

I have a situation in which I have to change bar color of it depending upon a value. I tired below but none of that works:

`$('#id').asPieProgress({barcolor: '#2e7d32'});`

`$('#id').asPieProgress({data-barcolor: '#2e7d32'});`

`$('#id').attr('data-barcolor', '#e53935');`

`$('#id').attr('barcolor', '#e53935');`

Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by giving the style on svg path element directly like below:

$('#id .pie-progress-svg svg path').attr("stroke", "#f44336");

Answer (score 1):

More correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress({
    namespace: 'pie_progress',
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    goal: 100,
    size: 160,
    speed: 40, // speed of 1/100
    barcolor: '#f44306', //yellow track color 
    barsize: '4',
    trackcolor: '#f2f2f2',
    fillcolor: 'none',
    numberCallback: function(n) {
      var percentage = Math.round(this.getPercentage(n));
            if (percentage > 0 && percentage <= 49) {
                $(this.$element).find('.pie_progress__svg svg path').attr("stroke", "#fa424a");
            }
            else if (percentage >= 50 && percentage <= 79) {
                $(this.$element).find('.pie_progress__svg svg path').attr("stroke", "#fdad2a");
            }
            else {
                $(this.$element).find('.pie_progress__svg svg path').attr("stroke", "#46c35f");
            }
            return percentage + '%';
    }
  });



  $('#button_start').on('click', function() {
    $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right [ChupChapCharli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2710206/chupchapcharli). I think a more elegant way would be to add a function that changes the barcode at runtime by extending the plugin.

Added a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/Dave_Weernink/8zakogew/53/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress({
    namespace: 'pie_progress',
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    goal: 100,
    size: 160,
    speed: 40, // speed of 1/100
    barcolor: '#f44306', //yellow track color 
    barsize: '4',
    trackcolor: '#f2f2f2',
    fillcolor: 'none',
    numberCallback: function(n) {
      var percentage = this.getPercentage(n);
      $('.pie_progress__number').text(percentage);
      if (percentage > 10 && percentage < 20) {
        $('.pie_progress svg path').attr("stroke", "#f44326");
      }
      if (percentage > 20 && percentage < 30) {
        $('.pie_progress svg path').attr("stroke", "#f44346");
      }
      if (percentage > 40 && percentage < 50) {
        $('.pie_progress svg path').attr("stroke", "#f44366");
      }
      if (percentage > 50) {
        $('.pie_progress svg path').attr("stroke", "#f44386");
      }
    },
  });



  $('#button_start').on('click', function() {
    $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');
  });

});
```